# Como faço para imprimir a quantidade de vezes que um item de um array aparece

Tags: javascript

> função deve ser escrita para receber somente um parâmetro: um array de notas. Ela deve retornar também um array com três elementos:

O primeiro, com a quantidade de notas iguais a 0 ou 1. Seriam os que não gostaram

O segundo, com a quantidade de notas iguais a 2 ou 3. Seriam os que acharam mediano

O terceiro, com a quantidade de notas iguais a 4 ou 5. Seriam os que gostaram

```
notas = [1,1,3,3,5,5]

function calculaGostos(notas){
   for(i =0; i <notas.length; i++){
       if(notas[i] >=4){
            var nGostaram = [notas[i] >=4]
        }if (notas <=1) {
            var nNaoGostaram = [notas[i] <=1]
        } else {
            var nMediano = [notas[i] ==2||notas[i] ==3] 
        }
for each()

        return [nGostaram,nNaoGostaram,nMediano]
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Bianca, sua pergunta não está clara, e o código que você colocou como exemplo, por estar errado não ajuda a esclarecer que é o problema, você poderia adicionar detalhes a sua pergunta para que possamos te ajudar

Comment: Desculpa Leo, é que nem eu entendi muito bem a lógica do exercício. Mas o que eu queria saber é como faço pra retonar quantas vezes um item aparece dentro de um array. Muito obriga pela atenção.

Comment: Você pode adicionar detalhes como por exemplo, como é este array, se é de números ou string, como você faz pra saber qual item você está procurando, se o item é passado como parâmetro... Coisas do tipo.

Comment: Reorganizei o código pra ficar mais fácil de ler e tentei utilizar o for each mas não sei a sintaxe, tentei multiplicar as variáveis dos if pela quantidade de elementos do array também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código faz uma coisa mas a sua pergunta diz outra coisa, de qualquer maneira irei demonstrar algumas maneiras de resolver o que acredito ser o seu problema, este é o nosso array de notas `notas = [1,1,3,3,5,5]`, a sua função pode ser feita no seguinte modo:

```js
const notas = [1,1,3,3,5,5];

function calculaGostos(notas){
  // Declare as 3 notas necessárias com valor inicial 0
  let nGostaram = 0;
  let nNaoGostaram = 0;
  let nMediano = 0;

  // Dentro ao for você não declara nenhum variável, mas usa as que acabamos de criar for do for, do contrário, variáveis criadas dentro do for, existem somente dentro do for 
  for(i =0; i < notas.length; i++){
     if(notas[i] >= 4){
          // O operador ++ equivale a nGostaram = nGostaram + 1;
          nGostaram++;
          
     } else if (notas[i] <= 1) {
          nNaoGostaram++;
     } else {
          nMediano++;
      }
  }
    
  // Return é última instrução dentro a uma função, está a indicar que a função terminou a sua execução e deve retornar um valor
  return [nGostaram,nNaoGostaram,nMediano]
}

console.log(calculaGostos(notas)); // [2, 2, 2]
```

O exemplo acima é uma maneira que pode ser usada para fazer o que você precisa, mas você pode facilitar a tua vida, por exemplo a função termina retornando um array de números, você não vai sempre se lembrar o que cada número significa e todas as vezes você vai procurar a função para saber o que ela te retorna? Vamos melhorar isso!

```js
const notas = [1,1,3,3,5,5];

function calculaGostos(notas){
  // Declare as 3 notas necessárias com valor inicial 0
  let gostaram = 0;
  let naoGostaram = 0;
  let mediano = 0;

  // Dentro ao for você não declara nenhum variável, mas usa as que acabamos de criar for do for, do contrário, variáveis criadas dentro do for, existem somente dentro do for 
  for(i =0; i < notas.length; i++){
     if(notas[i] >= 4){
          // O operador ++ equivale a nGostaram = nGostaram + 1;
          gostaram++;

     } else if (notas[i] <= 1) {
          naoGostaram++;
     } else {
          mediano++;
      }
  }

  // Mudamos os nomes das variáveis só para serem mais legiveis 
  // Retornamos um objeto e não um array
  return {gostaram, naoGostaram, mediano}
}
    
// Bem mais fácil de ler
console.log(calculaGostos(notas)); // {gostaram: 2, naoGostaram: 2, mediano: 2}
```

Reseve um pouco do teu tempo para ler um pouco sobre estes métodos que podem e serão úteis durante a tua vida de programadora Javascript:

> [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
>
> [Array find](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
>
> [Javascript Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)
>
> [Javascript Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
>
> [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs)

Comment: Muito obrigada! A primeira forma funcionou perfeitamente.